# popup в слайдере

Tags: javascript, html, css

Имеется связка Wordpress+WooCommerce. Установлен плагин покупки в 1 клик, который открывает поп-ап окно.
Также есть слайдер (slick slider) подключенный "внешне" от вордпресса и в слайдере крутятся "Похожие товары"
Вот проблема в том, что при нажатии кнопки  купить в 1 клик за основу берется контейнер слайдера и форма выходит за пределами видимости, если это не 6ой товар
Сталкивался ли кто-нибудь с таким вопросом.
Посмотреть можно [здесь](http://men.insignlab.ru/tovar/kondicioner-kozhi-skinclean/) Кнопка "Заказать" в блоке похожие товары

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала почините битую разметку.

```
<div class="price-wrap">
    <span class="price"><span class="amount">900&nbsp;<span class=rur >&#x440;<span>&#x443;&#x431;.</span></span></span></span>
</a>
```

Замените ее на:

```
<div class="price-wrap">
    <span class="price"><span class="amount">900&nbsp;<span class="rur">&#x440;<span>&#x443;&#x431;.</span></span></span></span>
</div>
```

---

Во-вторых, замените в этом коде
(файл `/wp-content/plugins/buy-one-click-woocommerce/js/form.js`):

```
jQuery(document).on('click', 'a.clickBuyButton', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var zixnAjaxUrl = getAjaxUrl();
    var butObj = this;

    var urlpost = window.location.href;
    var productid = jQuery(butObj).attr('data-productid');
    //alert(productid);

    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: zixnAjaxUrl,
        async: false,
        data: {
            action: 'getViewForm',
            urlpost: urlpost,
            productid: productid
        },
        success: function (response) {
            // console.log(response);
            jQuery('#formOrderOneClick').remove();
            jQuery(butObj).after(response);
            jQuery('.popup, .overlay').css('opacity', '1');
            jQuery('.popup, .overlay').css('visibility', 'visible');


        }
    });
});
```

Строчку `var butObj = this;` на `var butObj = $('body');`

Comment: Спасибо за решение!  Только оказывается плагин берет не данные выбраного товара, а товара который на странице. И по поводу разметки, это так выдает Вукоммерс.